# Orchard Taxonomies strange behaviour

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to understand how the Taxonomies module works because I would like to use it on my web site.

I have downloaded and installed the Taxonomies module from the Orchard Gallery.
I have setup everything as explained on the [module website](http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/documentation).

I have then created a Taxonomy named "Topics" and then a tree of terms like in the following picture

[image: term tree]

I have then edited the "Blog post" Content Type adding a new field named `Category` of type `Taxonomy Field`. This works very nice as I am able, when creating new posts, to specify the post taxonomy. Great.

Finally I have added a new widget, `Taxonomy Menu`, to my Home page. I have specified that the taxonomy is Topics, the root term is Parent taxonomy and that I want all sub levels showed.

I have created three sample posts each one with a different taxonomy.

[image]

The problem is that unfortunately I am only seeing the first level entries, like you can see in the following picture

[image]

Where do I am wrong???
Thanks for helping

**Please Note**: I am using the latest version of Orchard.

**EDIT**: These are the values from widget configuration:

- Title and Name: Categories
- Taxonomy: Topics (choosen from the dropdown)
- Root Term: "- Parent Taxonomy -" (choosen from the dropdown)
- Number of levels to display: 0
- All the check boxes left unchecked

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: the menu contains 1st and second level terms that are under term 1. Can you also show how you configured the widget?

Comment: Yes, you got it right, the menu only show levels of `Term 1`. I have edited the question to add the widget configuration. Please let me know if you need any further information...

Comment: Ah, well, I would expect, like you, that if no parent term is selected in the widget's configuration, the whole hierarchy should appear. It sounds like a bug to me, so you should probably file it on CodePlex. As a workaround, you should be able to create a "root" term and put your two current top-level terms under it. Clearly not perfect but might unblock you, maybe. But definitely file the bug.

Comment: Ok. I will file the bug adding a reference to this question that is clearly described with sample pictures. Thanks again for your help